# Как увеличить скорость прыжка в Unity 3D?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть скрипт прыжка. Он рабочий. Работает только тогда, когда персонаж находится на земле, но меня не устраивает скорость с которой он падает, нужно ее увеличить, как это сделать?
Уточнение:  нужно оставить туже высоту прыжка, но увеличить скорость с которой он будет преодолевать это расстояние.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Jump : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody Player;
    public float ForceJump = 10f;
    private bool IsGround = false;

    void Start()
    {
        Player = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    
   void OnTriggerStay(Collider col)
    {
       if (col.tag == "Ground")
       {
           IsGround = true;
           
       }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.tag == "Ground")
        {
            IsGround = false;
            
        }
    }

   
   void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Debug.Log("Нажатие");
        if (IsGround == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("IsGround == true");
            Vector3 ImpulsePlayer = new Vector3(0, ForceJump, 0);//Направление импульса
            Player.AddForce(ImpulsePlayer, ForceMode.Impulse);//Импульс
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Сделай игроку массу побольше или гравитацию

Comment: Похоже я неправильно сформулировал вопрос. Нужно оставить туже высоту прыжка, но увеличить скорость с которой он будет преодолевать это расстояние. А при увеличении массы, это расстояние уменьшается

Comment: Подкрутить ForceJump ?

Comment: Не-а. Увеличивая или уменьшая отдельно массу или силу прыжка уменьшается или увеличивается расстояние прыжка. Пропорциональное изменение параметров ничего не дает

Comment: Увеличить гравитацию.

Comment: О, то что нужно, спасибо :D

Comment: Не хочу ни на что намекать, но вариант с гравитацией был предложен @АлексейШиманский в самом первом комм... Кхе-кхе... В общем не важно.

Comment: Я так понимаю, ваш объект - 3D и на нем висит Rigidbody (3D), ведь вы используете OnTriggerStay и OnTriggerEnter (а не их 2D версии). Тогда как вы в итоге смогли изменить GravityScale, если [GravityScale](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-gravityScale.html) - это свойство [только](https://forum.unity.com/threads/why-does-rigidbody-3d-not-have-a-gravity-scale.440415/) компонента [Rigidbody2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.html)?

Comment: Изменил гравитацию в самом проекте

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Извиняюсь, как-то пропустил вариант изменения гравитации

Answer (score 0):

```
internal class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private AnimationCurve animation;

    private float ExpiredTime;
    private float Duration = 1;
    private float Height = 5;

    private void Update()
    {
        ExpiredTime += Time.deltaTime;

        if (ExpiredTime > Duration)
            ExpiredTime = 0;

        float progress = ExpiredTime / Duration;

        transform.position = new Vector3(0, animation.Evaluate(progress), 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

А почему бы при достижении некоего порогового уровня скорости по Y оси не делать дополнительный AddForce.

Костыль, но зато не повлияет на все остальные обьекты на сцене, в отличии от изменения настроек гравитации.

Answer (score 0):

В настройках проекта можно поменять силу гравитации
Edit -> Project Settings -> Physics -> Gravity поиграйся со значениями