# Слишком резкий прыжок unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Использовал классические инструменты для реализации передвижения персонажа: `Rigidbody` и `CapsuleCollider`. Для прыжка использовал функцию `Rigidbody.AddForce()`. При использовании данной функции прыжок не должен происходить резко как телепортация, но происходит обратное. Вот наглядный пример того, как прыгает объект в моем проекте

:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я же хочу добиться следующего результата:

[image: 2]

В чем может быть проблема, если я реализовал логику прыжка точно таким же образом, как и автор поста [Правильная реализация передвижения персонажа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/936027/352119) из клипа выше?

Еще информация, которая может оказаться важной: для более быстрого падения я в настройках Player Settings изменил значение Gravity для у с -9.81 на -200, так как до этого все объекты падали очень медленно. По моим наблюдениям, на мою проблему это вообще никак не влияет.

Вот код моего персонажа:

```
    using UnityEngine;

    public class HeroController : MonoBehaviour
    {
    //Oсновные параметры
    [SerializeField] float jumpForce;
    [SerializeField] float moveSpeed;
    [SerializeField] float rotationSpeed;
    [SerializeField] bool isGrounded;

    // Параметры геймплея
    private Vector3 moveVector;// направление  передвижения


    //Ссылки на компоненты
    private MobileController mController;
    private Animator ch_animator;
    private Rigidbody rb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        /*ch_animator = GetComponent<Animator>();*/
        mController = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Joystick")[0].GetComponent<MobileController>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Move();
        Jump();
    }

    private void Move()
    {
        //перемещение персонажа
        /*moveVector = Vector3.zero;*/
        moveVector.x = mController.Horizontal() * moveSpeed;
        moveVector.z = mController.Vertical() * moveSpeed;
        
        if (moveVector.magnitude > 0.1f)
        {
            Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(moveVector);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, rotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        rb.velocity = moveVector;//метод передвижения 
    }
    private void Jump()
    {
        if (Input.GetAxis("Jump") > 0)
        {
            if (isGrounded)
            {
                rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
            }
        }
    }
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        IsGroundedUpate(collision, true);
    }

    void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
    {
        IsGroundedUpate(collision, false);
    }

    private void IsGroundedUpate(Collision collision, bool value)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == ("Ground"))
        {
            isGrounded = value;
        }
    }
}
```

[Код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0#:%7E:text=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%3A-,using%20UnityEngine%3B,-//%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%8E%D1%82) автора статьи.

Comment: Попробуйте заменить Fixed Update на Update

Comment: В каком месте так-же если нет! Отключи исполнения метода `Move` и ищи проблему.

Comment: изменять гравитацию весьма плохая идея.  Желательно ознакомится с этими темами: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1279042/186752 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1320105/186752 , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7KiK0Aqtmzc , и вообще погуглить в стиле "unity make object fall faster". А вот менять всю гравитацию на сцене ради более быстрого падения это ОЧЕНЬ плохая идея. И да, эта гравитация 99% что и есть причина вот этого вопроса на стек оверфлоу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Jump сразу задавайте `IsGrounded = false`

Почему? Когда вы нажимаете пробел (так же известный, как `GetAxis("Jump")`, у вас этот метод вызывается не один раз, а несколько(Игрок может ещё находиться несколько кадров, поэтому ивент `OnCollisionExit()` не самый лучший выбор в этом плане).

Я не уверен, что именно в этом проблема, но это как минимум ошибка)

Comment: Старайтесь давать развернутые ответы. Почему, как это повлияет на результат и пр.

Comment: Спасибо за совет

Answer (score 0):

Проблема действительно была в методе Move(). Я заменил rb.velocity = moveVector на rb.AddForce(moveVector * moveSpeed, ForceMode.Impulse) и таким образом добился желаемой плавности.